# How to resize and draw an image using wxpython?

Tags: python, image, wxpython, resize, draw

I want to load an image, resize it to a given size and after draw it in a specific position in a panel.

All this using wxpython.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks guys, I'll try it later on and give the 'Accepted answer'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`wx.Image` has a `Scale` method that will do the resizing.  The rest is normal wx coding.

Here's a complete example for you.

```
import wx

def scale_bitmap(bitmap, width, height):
    image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
    return result

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, path):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent, -1)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(path)
        bitmap = scale_bitmap(bitmap, 300, 200)
        control = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bitmap)
        control.SetPosition((10, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Scaled Image')
    panel = Panel(frame, 'input.jpg')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: is it possible to do a onClick event on the image?

Comment: Yeah, just bind EVT_LEFT_DOWN on the StaticBitmap control.

Comment: Thakn you @FogleBird, is it possible to resize the `StaticBitmap` after it has been displayed once ? ie if the parent Window is resized, the `StaticBitmap` should be resized... Is this possible easily ?

Comment: Why, if you change style of frame, for ex. style= wx.NO_BORDER, the image does not load correctly ? What I need to do to load image in window without border ?

Comment: In wxPython version 4.0.1 with Python 2.7.13 I got two deprecation warnings. I used `image  = bitmap.ConvertToImage()` instead of `image  = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)` and `result = wx.Bitmap(image)` instead of `result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)`.

Answer (score 1):

First off I think the wxPython Docs and Demos do a *great* job explaining how to use  their libraries, especially because the demos can be played with on the fly to see the affect or you can revert to the original.  Here is the Windows link to download all the files:

http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#binaries

That said, here is the example code from the demo:

```
def runTest(frame, nb, log):
    bmp = wx.Image(opj('bitmaps/image.bmp'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    gif = wx.Image(opj('bitmaps/image.gif'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_GIF).ConvertToBitmap()
    png = wx.Image(opj('bitmaps/image.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
    jpg = wx.Image(opj('bitmaps/image.jpg'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()

    panel = wx.Panel(nb, -1)

    pos = 10
    wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, bmp, (10, pos), (bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight()))

    pos = pos + bmp.GetHeight() + 10
    wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, gif, (10, pos), (gif.GetWidth(), gif.GetHeight()))

    pos = pos + gif.GetHeight() + 10
    wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, png, (10, pos), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))

    pos = pos + png.GetHeight() + 10
    wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, jpg, (10, pos), (jpg.GetWidth(), jpg.GetHeight()))

    return panel
```

Here it shows how to load an image and displays it on a panel.  There are some objects not explained here, but it should give you the general gist.

Comment: That doesn't resize any image.  It just passes a size that could just as well be omitted.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, that just allows you to set a specific height and width of the image, as displayed, not resizing the image.  Answer updated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adding the image to a toolbar / listbook / toolbook etc.. you will have to convert it to a bitmap (usually only bitmaps allowed).

As far as i know you can't re-size a bitmap, therefore you will have to resize an image before and then convert it.

Here is a good example http://markandclick.com/1/post/2011/12/wxpython-resize-embedded-bitmap-before-adding-it-as-a-tool.html

Here is a copy from the example:

```
def getFolderBitmap():
  img = folder_icon.GetImage().Rescale(scaleW, scaleH)
  return img.ConvertToBitmap()
```