# wxPython remove window border

Tags: python, image, wxpython, border

I used the code from original source - [How to resize and draw an image using wxpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504143/how-to-resize-and-draw-an-image-using-wxpython/2504607#2504607)

The question is how to display window without border, with param-wx.NO_BORDER or wx.BORDER_NONE?

```
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Scaled Image', style= wx.BORDER_NONE)
```

When I use it the image shows cut in left upper corner, any suggestions?

Like this :

[image: result]

```
def scale_bitmap(bitmap, width, height):
    image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
    return result

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, path):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent, -1)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(path)
        bitmap = scale_bitmap(bitmap, 100, 100)
        control = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bitmap)
        # control.SetPosition((10, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Scaled Image', style= wx.BORDER_NONE)
    panel = Panel(frame, 'onewayr.jpg')
    frame.SetPosition((100, 100))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What widgets are you putting on the frame? What you show in the image is common if there are one or more child widgets and nothing is being done to manage their size or position. Adding a minimal but runnable application to your question will help greatly.

Comment: Please, kindly see updated code ! If you delete (style= wx.BORDER_NONE) its shown properly !

Answer (score 1):

You will get the picture at the specified size using:

```
control = wx.StaticBitmap(parent, -1, bitmap)
```

This, however, is not the canonical way of defining Panels and Frames. Most commonly, the `Frame` has sizers and the `Panel` is located in a slot of the sizer. The sizer do all the job of positioning and expanding the contents of the panel.

For example (Using wxPython Phoenix version):

```
import wx

def scale_bitmap(impath, width, height):
    image = wx.Image(impath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.Bitmap(image)
    return result

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, impath=None):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent, -1)
        bitmap = scale_bitmap(impath, 100, 100)
        self.control = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bitmap)


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, imgpath=None): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.panel = Panel(self, imgpath)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('red')

        self.SetSize(150,150)
        self.SetPosition((100,100))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None, imgpath=r'C:/Users/joaquin/Desktop/llave.jpg') 
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here I gave a red color to the Panel to show that it fills all the space of the 150x150 Frame while the picture, which was scaled to 100x100, is positioned at a default position on the Panel (upper left).

[image]